# Function Ready(fn) that trigger function fn after page content load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, parsing, google-chrome-extension

i'm currently writing a chrome extension. I don't use any kind of a js framework(only pure js). So here is my problem:
I'm trying to parse the data out of web store clicking on categories/items/items details. But their website has some kind of script that loads new data into body without reloading the page [[something like this](https://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/)]. So when my script works, it kinda trying to get DOM elements when new DOM isnt loaded. I've tried

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
   //my code goes here
})
```

But it doesn't work because the page isn't reloading. So the page after first load still has the same state.
After reading some internet blogs,websites etc. I came to

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted",()=>{
    //some code
})
```

It does the job but event is triggering every time items on page is added. So is there is method to wait until all items are loaded. Or maybe

So here is my final question. How to write a function ready(fn) that would trigger fn() after content loads

Comment: If you insert the object. why you don't invoke the init method?

Comment: See [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954).

Comment: then remove the eventlistener after getting the dom you needed